# Добавление одного специального элемента в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

**Дано:** `RecyclerView` с элементами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Нужно:**
Сделать так чтоб при добавлении новых элементов в список, последний элемент, который там есть не изменялся и при нажатии на него открылось новое активити

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder categoryViewHolder, int i) {
    if (i < getItemCount()-1) {
 // тут не делать ничего?
    } else {
        // последний элемент

        Category lastCategory = new Category("lasItem",  R.drawable.ic_favorites);
        categories.add(lastCategory);

    }
    categoryViewHolder.bind(categories.get(i), listener);
    categoryViewHolder.categoryName.setText(categories.get(i).name);
    categoryViewHolder.categoryPhoto.setImageResource(categories.get(i).photoId);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы работал `RecyclerView`, вы делаете адаптер. Адаптер создает элементы из какого-то источника, обычно это список или курсор. Допустим, список лежит в поле `list`. Вы можете добавить один неизменяемый элемент списка в конец следующим образом:

Первое: общее количество элементов будет длина `list` + 1:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (list == null) return 0;
    return list.size() + 1;
}
```

Второе: при отображении данных для последнего элемента вы показываете заранее заготовленный элемент и планируете специальное действие:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(OfferHolder holder, int position) {
    if (position < getItemCount()-1) {
        Offer o = list.get(position);
        holder.show(o, false);
    } else {
        // последний элемент
        holder.show(mySpecialOffer, true);
    }
}
```

Третье. В холдере по второму параметру метода `show()` вы определяете поведение: либо это стандартное действие, либо специфичное для последнего элемента (в вашем случае - переход на новое активити).

Comment: объясните пожалуйста по поводу `onBindViewHolder` не совсем понимаю, добавил свой `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: onBindViewHolder нужен для того, чтобы в созданном элементе списка показать нужные данные. последний элемент у вас особенный и живет своей жизнью. это нужно отразить в коде: для последнего элемента есть заранее заготовленные данные, и есть отличное от остальных поведение.

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста правильно изменил код?

Comment: @java как минимум, то что у вас вне условия нужно перенести туда, где написано "не делать ничего". Вроде в ответе это явно видно

Comment: @pavlofff, уже понял, спасибо